# Using IPv6 with docker selenium/node-chrome-debug

Tags: python, docker, selenium-chromedriver, ipv6

I wrote a small script that uses selenium remote webdriver and it looks like this to connect to the docker container:

```
browser = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

My problem is now that I have a dual-stack docker container (IPv4/6) and for IPv6 sites, it does not connect with IPv6 but IPv4.

How can I change my script or the docker container itself that it uses only IPv6?

Best,
Gregor